# Replace unknown text using regex

Tags: java, regex

Given string "abcxxxdef"

**This xxx could be any unknown string.**

abc and def is known.

xxx needs to be replaced with "(xxx)" without quotes.

output : abc(xxx)def

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript:

```js
var string = "abcxxxdef";

console.log(string.replace(/(abc)(.*)(def)/g, "$1($2)$3"))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "abcxxxxdef";
    s = s.replaceAll("(abc)(.*)(def)", "$1($2)$3");
    System.out.println(s);
}
```